# Bucket policy not finding the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have created a first bucket policy to grant full access to a specific IAM user, so far with only one policy, that configuration goes well.

[image]

Now I'm trying to add another policy in my code. I use the official policies generator [here](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). However, when I apply the code I get an error saying: "**Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement**".

If we dive into the policy code is very clear that for every policy was assigned a resource.

[image]

Can please someone in the community help me to understand where is the error in the policy that includes two different rules. thanks so much I appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s3:ListBucket` is a bucket level permission to list all the objects. In a Bucket policy, you can only apply object-level permission, ie., anything inside the bucket . So, If you remove `s3:ListBucket` it would work.

Comment: I had to validate as well the list of available actions because either ways couple of them don't match with the available actions in policies.